# when accessing the login again, the user has the same option selected (kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

I have an app that I would like that when performing the login and the user selects a radio button in the option he wants, this information is already selected when he accesses the account again with the same login, only if it is the same login, if it is another perform the normal process of selecting an option.

Comment: What platform is this for?

Comment: android studio.